# Socket.io on multiple servers with HaProxy

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, emit

I have `HAProxy` which serve multiple servers with nodejs on expressjs. I have added to that express socket.io and to make them work i tried to connect them with `socket.io-redis` and `socket.io-ioredis`. All looks to be connected without any error but when an user get his socket connected with different server from other user, their emits don't read don't send to other servers.
`Nodejs setup`

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-ioredis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'serverIP', port: 6565 }));
server.listen(6565);
```

How do i do the emit:
`io.to(roomID).emit(event, object);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that port on which redis was connecting in server was blocked by the firewall.